# How get PPT 2010 to produce 220 ppi jpegs?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, jpeg, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I've put together a photo collage as a single slide in PPT 2010 using a custom page size of 20"x16". When I save the slide as a jpeg, I use the Tools>Compress Pictures>Target output option to set the resolution to 220 ppi (which is also the default). This should yield a jpg with dimensions 4400x3520. Unfortunately, the resolution I get is 1920x1536, meaning that PPT saved the jpg at only 96 ppi.

How can I get PPT to produce a jpg of the appropriate dimensions?

Comment: A workaround can be to convert it in pdf and then with [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) in jpg, specifying density and size.

Comment: @Hastur: I'll look into the workaround if there's no direct solution, but I'm hoping there's a way to get PPT to produce the resolution it seems to promise.

Comment: Set the page size to 45.83"x36.67".  That will give you the resolution.  Once you have the jpg, you can easily change the inch dimensions or ppi.

Comment: @fixer1234: Clever idea, but PPT is not so easily thwarted. Changing the page size as you suggests causes PPT to drop the resolution to 67 dpi, thus yielding a jpg of 3070x2456. I'll play around to see if making the page size even bigger forces PPT to do what it's supposed to do without any finagling. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Try `save as PNG`

Comment: @wbeard52: Saving as PNG makes no difference: the same resolution is produced as for JPG.

Comment: PowerPoint 2010 and prior will not export images of over 3070 pixels.  Known limitation.  PPT 2013 and up will go larger, considerably larger.

Comment: Per https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/827745#bookmark-limitations, the limitation actually appears to be 3072 pixels.

Comment: MS Support doesn't always get out in the real world much.  Depending on the version of PPT, you may need to limit resolution to somewhat under 3072 or you can get black lines at right and bottom sides of exported images.